# Uploading data to s3 using AWSAccessKey, AWSSecretKey, bucket name and upload path.

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an iOS app developed using Objective c and wanted to upload some data to s3. But i have only the above mentioned credentials to access s3 and upload data. Being a beginner to iOS programming, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please see: [AWS Mobile SDK for iOS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/)

Comment: Which kind of data you want to upload on s3 bucket

Comment: I did but am still not clear about how to access s3 using above keys, earlier it was using AmazonS3Client but it's absent from the current sdk version.

Comment: data is a .csv file

Comment: Refer this one http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/s3transfermanager.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is code that works for me and I recently updated to the latest Amazon SDK.

```
- (AWSServiceConfiguration *)setupAmazonServiceConfiguration {

    AWSStaticCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSStaticCredentialsProvider alloc] initWithAccessKey:awsAccessKeyId secretKey:awsSecretKey];

    AWSServiceConfiguration *awsServiceConfiguration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1 credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];

    [AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = awsServiceConfiguration;

    return awsServiceConfiguration;

}

- (void)upload:(NSString *)keyPath
      fileName:(NSString *)fileName
       success:(void (^)())success
       failure:(void (^)())failure {


    @try {
        AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest *uploadRequest = [[AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest alloc] init];
        uploadRequest.bucket = [self bucketPath];
        uploadRequest.key = keyPath;
        uploadRequest.body =  [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileName];

        AWSS3TransferManager *transferManager = [AWSS3TransferManager defaultS3TransferManager];
        [[transferManager upload:uploadRequest] continueWithExecutor:[AWSExecutor mainThreadExecutor] withBlock:^id _Nullable(AWSTask * _Nonnull task) {
            if (task.error != nil) {
                failure();
            } else {
                 success();
            }
            return nil;
        }];
    }
    @catch(NSException *e) {
        failure();
    }
}
```